# How to do side channel attack on smart cards?

Tags: attacks, smartcard, side-channel

Assume that I have a  smart card and I want to do a differential power side channel attack on its mutual authentication mechanism.

This is the mutual authentication mechanism that my card using(Let assume that the authentication key is *AuthKey* and it is shared between the card and the user already):

1. User send a command to the card to request for a random number + a random number named *challenge 1*
2. Card return its random number named *Challenge 2* + `Card_enc1 = encrypt(AuthKey , Challenge 1)` to user.
3. User receive `Card_enc1` and compare it with output of `User_enc1 = encrypt(AuthKey , Challenge 1)`. If they was equal, it returns `User_enc2 = encrypt (AuthKey, Challenge 2)` to the card.
4. Card receive `User_enc2` and compare it with `Card_enc2 = encrypt (AuthKey, Challenge 2)`. If they was equal then the card and reader are successfully authenticated.

As you see above, the user didn't send the `AutheKey` while in the documents that I read on side channel attacks the attacker must set different values for encryption key and encrypt different data with that key.

Now, the question is, how can I do side channel attack on this authentication procedure?

A step by step answer is more useful.